# PHP: Sending a constant through a form and auto-sending it

Tags: php, forms, web

For a website, I need to route users to their own page. I have a login form, which sends data to a PHP file to check if the user's information is correct, and if so, forwarding the user to their page. The only problem is that I need to validate the user on arrival, to check if they logged in or just typed out the URL. I plan to use this with a POST, but how can I auto-send the constant (i.e. "logged-in")? Is there a way to do that through an HTML form (outputted from an echo) and sending it when the page loads? Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: I understand that I must use Sessions, but whenever the page redirects it clears the session. The whole reason I was asking this was because I needed a way to keep the session active. How do I redirect in a way that doesn't clear the session?

Comment: Read about sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PHP file that validates their credentials, start a "session".  You can then apply session variables that can be called at any time while the session is valid.  You can do this with POST, which is sounds like you're using, or by querying a database upon validation.

For example, upon validation:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$security_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userList WHERE username = '$username'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($security_check);
$_SESSION['userId'] = $row['userId'];
$_SESSION['userFullName'] = $row['userFullName'];
```

On subsequent pages, you can put the following code at the top to check if the user logged in.  If not, it will kick them back to the index page; otherwise the $_SESSION variables will be maintained.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('index.php?login=no') </script>";
}
?>
```

As suggested in the comments, I would recommend doing some further research on sessions to get a full understanding of how they work.

Comment: But how do I keep the session after redirecting? I can't find a way to keep the session the same. Whenever the page loads I check the session, which is always empty. (I am using the <meta> tag to redirect, though only because I couldn't get this to work using the header() method).